# How to log incoming request and response?

Tags: scala, akka, akka-http

I am using Akka HTTP and would like to log every incoming request and outgoing result. I know, that it exists a [logRequestResult](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-http/current/routing-dsl/directives/debugging-directives/logRequestResult.html) directive, but how to use it? Or is it the right for my purpose?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is the directive you are looking for, and I agree - the official documentation is a bit hard to grasp on.

Here is how an endpoint with `logRequestResult` would look like:

```scala
    val requestHandler: Route = logRequestResult("req/resp", Logging.InfoLevel) {
        handleExceptions(errorHandler) {
            endpointRoutes
        }
    }

    def start()(implicit actorSystem: ActorSystem,
                actorMaterializer: ActorMaterializer): Future[Http.ServerBinding] =
        Http().bindAndHandle(
            handler = requestHandler,
            interface = host,
            port = port)
```

Notice you can choose a generic prefix for each request-response entry, i.e, `req/resp`, as well as the logging level on which the request-response log is available, i.e. `Logging.InfoLevel`.

The above example produces log lines similar to the one below:

```
[your-actor-system-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-19] INFO  akka.actor.ActorSystemImpl - req/resp: Response for
  Request : HttpRequest(HttpMethod(GET),http://<host>/<path>,List(Host: <host>, Connection: close: <function1>),HttpEntity.Strict(none/none,ByteString()),HttpProtocol(HTTP/1.1))
  Response: Complete(HttpResponse(200 OK,List(),HttpEntity.Strict(text/plain; charset=UTF-8,OK),HttpProtocol(HTTP/1.1)))
```

Happy hakking :)